# How To Modify/Edit Traccar Template

Tags: html, tracking, backtracking, traccar

I am using traccar open source GPS tracking system, and I want to edit/modify some html elements but I cant

I want Modify/Edit Traccar Template there is a any way, please help.

I have downloaded traccar and checked all file in traccar directory but there is a no html files

please suggest how to edit/modify traccar code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation on how to build the app from the source code:

https://www.traccar.org/build/

If you're interested in changing only the web app, check the links under the **Build Web App** section.